# access local pc filesystem with hololens

Tags: c#, uwp, hololens

I'm trying to find a way to access a local PCs file system with a microsoft hololens on the same network. For example. I want to be able to open a txt document on the hololens and save it to my PC. I can't seem to find any relatable documentation online. Basically all I want to do is use the Hololens as a monitor to my PC. Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible to map the network path as a unit in your hololens file system?

Comment: Maybe this link helps: [UWP Access a file on a network drive?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/e822c960-f15d-4789-9ff2-040212d0a67c/uwpaccess-a-file-on-a-network-drive?forum=wpdevelop)

Comment: I think your best option is to use OneDrive to sync files between both devices.